# Update fields on form from fields on another (Lotus Notes)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have a list of printers stored in a printer keyword section that have fields like the serial of the ink they use for each of their colours and such. I want to make it so when I create a new user form and say that they have "X" Printer, it will grab that keyword form and pull all the ink types that it uses and save itself on the user form.

@GetDocField is the method I know I have to use but I do not know how to acquire the correct form saved from a list of forms based on a selection I make on which printer the user has.

Comment: Knut's answer is most likely correct. Here's a vocabulary hint: In the Notes/Domino world, a "form" refers only to a definition of UI and programming. The actual stuff that is saved when using the form is referred to as a "document", so when you say "acquire the correct form saved from a list of forms" I believe you really mean "find the appropriaate document saved with a given form".  Your question would have a very different answer if you were actually trying to read keyword data from forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @DbLookup to get the data from printer documents.

```
FIELD ink1 := @DbLookup(""; ""; "viewPrinters"; "XPrinter"; "ink1"; [FAILSILENT]);
```

The line above reads item "ink1" in printer's "XPrinter" document in view "viewPrinters" in current database and writes it to item "ink1" in current document. You would copy every field this way. The view "viewPrinters" has to to have a first sorted column with the printer names.

It might be more efficient to define all fields you want to grab in a column separated by a special character and get them all at once with

```
FIELD allFields:= @DbLookup(""; ""; "viewPrinters"; "XPrinter"; 2; [FAILSILENT]);
```

You can stay with @GetDocField too if you read the document ID of your printer document:

```
_docId := @Text(@DbLookup(""; ""; "viewPrinters"; "XPrinter"; "";
                                              [RETURNDOCUMENTUNIQUEID]));
@If(@IsError(_docId); @Return(""); "");
FIELD ink1 := @GetDocField(_docId: "ink1");
```

It might be even more efficient to use LotusScript instead. But i assumed from your question you prefer a formula solution.

Comment: Although this is not the method I used, this was a very good answer. I managed to create a complex but hopefully equally efficient method to sorting this problem.